# wait till function completes calling other functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function1 that calls another function2. Function2 has a for loop in which it calls function3. I want to execute a statement after all 3 calls to function 3 have finished executing. How do I achieve it?

```
function1: function(){
    function2(args, doSomething(returnValue) {
        if(returnValue == true){
            // do something here
        }
    });
}

function2: function(args, callback){
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        function3(args);
    }

    // if function3 completed all 3 times
    callback(true);
}
```

Comment: Keyword to google: promises

Comment: @zerkms this is a part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6) proposal. I want something that supports all major browsers. Do you think it will work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: there are loads of ES5 libraries. https://promisesaplus.com/implementations

Comment: The *calls* to `function3()` *will* have finished executing. How `function3` signals that it has completed an asynchronous task is left unclear in your question.

Comment: @Bergi, I can do whatever I want in function 3. Please suggest.

Comment: Well, it seems to do something asynchronous, so at least one callback would be involved. @zerkms is right, you should consider using [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources), they greatly simplify dealing with asynchronous results.

Comment: Promises are not something magical. They're just a design pattern. As such they can be implemented in javascript. I've implemented a promise library myself in order to figure out how they work. So promises are pure javascript - no need to update the language or interpreter. The promises in ES6 is basically an addition to the standard library (which includes the Math object, the DOM etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is to make a variable that increments each time the for loop runs in `function2()` and check if it is high enough outside of the for loop.

```
var timesCalled = 0
function1: function(){
    function2(args, doSomething(returnValue) {
        if(returnValue == true){
            // do something here
        }
});
}
function2: function(args, callback){
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        function3(args);
        timesCalled++
    }

    if (timesCalled >= 2){// if function3 completed all 3 times
        callback(true);
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure that function3 does what you want it to 3 times then put the increment in function3. I hope this helps!